# Machine Learning Regression using Python Tensorflow on very noisy data

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, neural-network

I am trying to find the multiplicative bias of a galaxy shape-fitting software. To do this, we simulate some images from known data, then apply the software to the images and see how well they predict the data. To find the bias function I am trying to use a machine learning regression algorithm. The idea is to feed the true data, the data predicted by the software and some additional parameters (like galaxy size) to the neural network, so it can then predict the errors. The problem is this is not working.

Here is how I split the data into training and testing (df is the data frame I am working with):

```
train_data, test_data, train_target, test_target = model_selection.train_test_split(
df.drop(columns=['g']), df.g, test_size=0.3, random_state=0)  #Splitting into training and testing data
```

I now build the neural network:

```
def build_model():
nlayers = 1
# Initialising the ANN
model = keras.Sequential()

# Adding the input layer and the first hidden layer
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(16, activation=tf.nn.relu ,input_shape=(train_data.shape[1],)))

# Adding the hidden layers (found N = len(train_data)/(neurons*10))
for i in range(nlayers):
    model.add(keras.layers.Dense(units = 16,activation=tf.nn.relu))

# Adding the output layer
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(units = 16,activation = "linear"))
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(units = 1))
opti = keras.optimizers.Nadam(0.0001)
model.compile(optimizer = opti, loss = 'mean_squared_error', metrics=['mse'])

return model
```

I then train it:

```
EPOCHS = 20
early_stop = keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', patience=20)

history = model.fit(train_data, train_target, epochs=EPOCHS, validation_split=0.2, verbose=1, callbacks=[early_stop])
```

[Here you can see how the loss function decreases](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TiOy3.png)

However when I ask it to predict values the following happens:

```
test_predictions = model.predict(test_data).flatten()
plt.scatter(test_target[:1000], test_predictions[:1000])
plt.title("Is it working??")
plt.xlabel('True Values')
plt.ylabel('Predictions')
plt.axis('equal')
plt.xlim(plt.xlim())
plt.ylim(plt.ylim())
_ = plt.plot([-100, 100], [-100, 100])
plt.savefig("Predictions.png")
plt.show()
```

[Predictions vs true values. Line is y = x equation, if it was working I would expect values to be around y=x](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mFfOO.png)

I don't have much experience with neural networks, so I don't know if I am doing something wrong, if it is just the data, or if I should be using some feature I do not know about.

Any help is appreciated!!

Comment: Is there a reason for why are you using regression with neural networks? That looks like an overkill to me. Also, why tensor-flow instead of scikt-learn linear regression (or which regression you have in mind)?

Comment: Is the picture of the loss decrease the training or validation loss?
Also how much data do you have, your network has 3 hidden layers with 16 neurons each, have you tried using less layers?

Comment: Hi, I have tried using scikit-learn with similar results.

Comment: It is the training loss. I have around 10 million data points. I have tried using less layers, it doesn't seem to work any better. Thanks!!!